# limits and infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around some of the 'rules' of limits. For example,

$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{x^2 -2} - \sqrt{x^2 + 1}
$$

becomes

$$
\sqrt{\lim_{x\to \infty} (x^2) -2} - \sqrt{\lim_{x\to \infty}(x^2) + 1}
$$

which, after graphing, seems to approach zero. My question is how do you know for sure the answer is zero without graphing? Thanks!

Comment: Your second expression is indeterminate whereas your first evaluates to a number.  Thus $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left[\sqrt{x^2 -2} - \sqrt{x^2 + 1}\right] \ne \sqrt{\lim_{x\to \infty} (x^2) -2} - \sqrt{\lim_{x\to \infty}(x^2) + 1}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\left[\sqrt {x^2 - 2} - \sqrt{x^2 + 1}\right]\dot\, \frac{\sqrt {x^2 - 2} + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{\sqrt {x^2 - 2} + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} = \frac{x^2 - 2 - (x^2 + 1)}{\sqrt {x^2 - 2} + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$$

Comment: Be careful to the brackets ;-)

Comment: @AaronMaroja Now do you see?

Comment: You don't see the pair of brackets I added or you don't see why without them the fraction would only multiply the second term?

Answer (score 0):

multiply by $$\sqrt{x^2 -2} + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$$
You'll get : 
$$\frac{-3}{\sqrt{x^2 -2} + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}} \rightarrow 0$$

Comment: No, it doesn't work !

Comment: This seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\sqrt{x^2 -2} - \sqrt{x^2 + 1}=(\sqrt{x^2 -2} - \sqrt{x^2 + 1})\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2 -2} + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{\sqrt{x^2 -2} +\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}=\frac{-3}{\sqrt{x^2 -2} + \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$$